# Android getPackageInfo without getPackageManager

Tags: java, android

Is there any possibility to get the versionCode of an App without the getPackageManager? My Problem is, that i want a public Configuration class which have no Activity, so the getPackageManager() does not work. Any Idea?

My current Code:

```
PackageInfo pinfo;
try {
    pinfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
} catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
    pinfo = null;
}

appVersion = pinfo.versionCode;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take an instance of [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) in the constructor of your non-activity class and use that to call all such methods.

Something like this:

```
public class NonActivityClass implements SensorListener{
Context mContext;
public NonActivtiyClass(Context context) {
this.mContext = context;
}
//Rest of your code
}
```

Then do this to create an object of that class in your Activtiy's `onCreate()`:

```
NonActivityClass nac = new NonActivityClass(this);
```

Comment: Can't i just use something like `NonActivityClass(this).appVersion` ?

Comment: Uh, what would that achieve? I thought you were trying to use the packageManager from a normal class. You can call all of the things you use in Activites by using mContext.methodWhichYouUseInActivtiy();.

Comment: Maybe my thoughts are just wrong.. but i want to call the appVersion as fast (with as less code) as possible, but i need to call it very often, so it would be great if i don't need to declare a "new Class" first...

Comment: Use the code I gave you in the onCreate() method, and then whenever you want to call appVersion use nac.yourMethodName();

Comment: Yes.. this would be possible too.. Ok, if there is no other way, i will do it that way. Thank you!

Comment: Remember that you can only call that method after you've run that line of code in the onCreate(). If you call it before, then you'll get a NullPointerException on the mContext variable.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to pass a reference to the `Context` (preferably using `getApplicationContext()`, to prevent accidental memory leaks) to the public `Configuration` class. There is no other way to retrieve the `versionCode` of your application. You have to use `PackageManager`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to get app version code of the current app:

```
public int getAppVersionCode() {
    return BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
}
```